# TiledMap blocks makes Animation invisible

Tags: libgdx

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Got it fixed. Thanks to anyone who tried to help me.
New Code:

```
mapManager.render();
spriteBatchForeground.setProjectionMatrix(Main.getGraphicsManager().getAdvCamera().getCamera().combined);
spriteBatchForeground.begin();
    worldManager.render(delta, spriteBatchForeground);
    animationManager.render(spriteBatchForeground);
    particleEffectManager.render(delta, spriteBatchForeground);
spriteBatchForeground.end();
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I just implemented my animations but now I discovered a problem with my TiledMap.

Here some Screenshots:

[image]

Code for 1

```
spriteBatchForeground.begin();
// mapManager.render();

spriteBatchForeground.setProjectionMatrix(
    Main.getGraphicsManager().getAdvCamera().getCamera().combined );
worldManager.render(delta, spriteBatchForeground);
animationManager.render(spriteBatchForeground);
particleEffectManager.render(delta, spriteBatchForeground);
spriteBatchForeground.end();
```

Code for 2

```
spriteBatchForeground.begin();
mapManager.render();

spriteBatchForeground.setProjectionMatrix(
    Main.getGraphicsManager().getAdvCamera().getCamera().combined );
worldManager.render(delta, spriteBatchForeground);
animationManager.render(spriteBatchForeground);
particleEffectManager.render(delta, spriteBatchForeground);
spriteBatchForeground.end();
```

Issue:

The animation isn't drawing when I enable the drawing for the tiledmap.
I have no idea why this happens...

Comment: Could you describe the issue you're having and what is the expected behaviour? It's difficult to see what is the issue just by looking at the image: we don't know what to look for.

Comment: edited it at the end